# Preventing nose from discovering a package named "setup"?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I've got a directory tree that looks like:

```
$ find . -name '*.py' -ls
1315965    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 roy      roy            16 May 25 23:09 ./foo/__init__.py
1445517    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 roy      roy            16 May 25 23:09 ./foo/setup/__init__.py
```

When I run nose, it imports foo.setup, believes it's a fixture, and attempts to run it, resulting in:

```
TypeError: Attribute setup of <module 'foo' from '/home/roy/play/nose/foo/__init__.pyc'> is not a python function. Only functions or callables may be used as fixtures.
```

Is there some way to tell nose not to do that?  I tried putting `__test__ = False` in both `foo/__init__.py` and `foo/setup/__init__.py`, to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the -I (--ignore-files) flag in the command line?

Comment: That seems like it would work, thanks.  As it turns out, we ended up reorganizing the code tree to avoid this problem, but I'll keep --ignore-files in mind the next time it comes up.

Comment: For me I used `./manage.py test --ignore-files setup.py` Thanks!