# Disable nose running setup()

Tags: python, python-sphinx, nose, doctest

The [`nose`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/) package is often used to run [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) as well as tests in dedicated test files. It appears that even in doctest files, it attempts to run the `setup` and `teardown` fixtures.

When the module for doctesting happens to require a function named `setup` for some other purpose -- it may be a [Sphinx extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/tutorial.html#the-setup-function), for example -- nosetests will call `setup` and fail.

To be clear, here is an example:

```
def my_tricky_function(arg):
    """Do something testable

    >>> my_tricky_function(1)
    2
    """
    return arg + arg


def my_extension(app):
    ...


def setup(app):
    """Establish sphinx hooks"""
    app.connect('build-finished', my_extension)
```

Running `nosestests` results in:

```
File ".../site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 291, in setUp
    self.setupContext(ancestor)
  File ".../site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 314, in setupContext
    try_run(context, names)
  File ".../site-packages/nose/util.py", line 468, in try_run
    return func(obj)
  File "sphinx_ext.py", line 14, in setup
    app.connect('build-finished', my_extension)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

(Note: when `setup` accepts an argument, nosetest passes the scope in which `setup` is a name, in this case the module.)

Note that the following do not (seem to) apply:

- adding an attribute [`__test__ = False`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120148/disabling-python-nosetests) (or using [this decorator](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest)) to `setup` doesn't stop it being called.
- there is no command-line option equivalent to [`--ignore-files`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758773/preventing-nose-from-discovering-a-package-named-setup)
- setting `my_tricky_function.setup = None` does not stop the module-level setup (h/t @alecxe)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - does setting `my_tricky_function.setup = None` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following somewhat hacky solution: add another function `setup_module` which will hide `setup` from nose.

```
...

def setup(app):
    """Establish sphinx hooks"""
    app.connect('build-finished', my_extension)

def setup_module():
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

While joeln's own answer is nifty, it does pollute the top-level namespace of the module a bit.

I would check the arguments to `setup()` to distinguish a nosetests call from a normal call. In your case, if `app` is a module (or has no `connect` attribute), simply return and do nothing.

```py
def setup(app):
    """Establish sphinx hooks"""
    if hasattr(app, 'connect'):
        app.connect('build-finished', my_extension)
```

I had this issue where a custom `setuptools.setup(**kwargs)` tripped up nose. While nosetests called it without any arguments, normal usage of `setup()` would always pass in some keyword arguments, which allows me to distinguish the two cases.